# Benchmarking Hadoop Map-Reduce application

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, benchmarking, scheduling

I need to compare two Hadoop scheduling algorithms by job execution time. 
What could I use to get the duration of the execution for all tasks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JobTracker web UI gives you very useful reports which allow to compare everything up to available logs for every mapper and reducer.

Also look on `mrbench` class inside `hadoop-test.jar` archive. There is plenty of information on the net about its usage for Hadoop cluster benchmarking like [this article](http://www.michael-noll.com/blog/2011/04/09/benchmarking-and-stress-testing-an-hadoop-cluster-with-terasort-testdfsio-nnbench-mrbench/).

Answer (score 0):

You can see detailed information about the tasks and jobs from the address:

```
http://hostnameofmachinerunningtheJobTracker:50030/jobtracker.jsp
```

you can have other information from [link](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2009/08/hadoop-default-ports-quick-reference/)

Comment: It should actually be the hostname of machine running the JobTracker service. If it is not on the machine same as NameNode then you have to  keep that in mind. And there is nothing like hostname of HDFS. HDFS is spread across all the machines. There is either NameNode hostname or DataNode hostname.

Comment: I am running the jobs on a remote grid, from a terminal and I don't have access to an interface to view this information. Does Hadoop also store this information in a log file?